# Replace comma with semi-colon in a site column

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a site column with few email address's separated by comma. I want to replace those with semi-colon. Can anyone of you please provide the calculated column to it or any other alternate way.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, an alternative would be to use a person/group field that is defined to allow multiple persons.  This ensures that 1) the email addresses are valid and 2) will automatically drop in semicolons as delimiters.

If that won't work, then the better option in my opinion would be to have a javascript or jquery function included in the new/edit forms to search and replace the commas with semi-colons in the particular field on save.  Simply altering it with an XSLT view isn't going to help you should you need to use the data in a workflow, which I think you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in formula for that. But a can build complex formula. [Here](http://home.jordananderson.us/calculatedcolumntextsubstituation) is an example.

The better way is to customize list view with xslt. You can do it easily with SharePoint Designer.